# Stopping propagation of mousedown/mouseup from a click handler

Tags: javascript, jquery, mouseevent

**[Here's a DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/6gw4x)**.

I have two `divs`, an inner and an outer:

```
<div id="outer">
    <div id="inner"></div>
</div>
```

With some CSS so you can see which is which:

```
#outer {
    width: 250px;
    height: 250px;
    padding: 50px;
    background: yellow;
}

#inner {
    width: 250px;
    height: 250px;
    background: blue;
}
```

I try to stop propagation of `mousedown` and `mouseup` events from within a `click` handler like so:

```
$('#inner').on('click', function(e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
    $(this).css({'background': 'green'});
    return false;
});

$('#outer').on('mousedown', function(e) {
    $(this).css({'background': 'green'});
});

$('#outer').on('mouseup', function(e) {
    $(this).css({'background': 'yellow'});
});
```

This doesn't seem possible. What does work is calling `.stopPropagation` from within other `mousedown` and `mouseup` calls, as shown here **([another DEMO)](http://jsfiddle.net/6gw4x/1/)**:

```
$('#inner').on('mousedown', function(e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
    return false;
});

$('#inner').on('mouseup', function(e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
    return false;
});
```

I may have already answered my own question, but I'm not sure if my approach is the best or most reasonable. Is this the right way to stop an event bubbling up to a `mousedown` and `mouseup`?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Yes. Since mouseclick and mousedown/mouseup are different events, you can't get at one from the other at all - you have to do it from within your own mousedown/mouseup handlers. What you can do is refactor that into a generic method to use in both places:

```
stopPropagation('#inner', 'mousedown');
stopPropagation('#inner', 'mouseup');

function stopPropagation(id, event) {
    $(id).on(event, function(e) {
        e.stopPropagation();
        return false;
    });
}
```

Comment: Watch out for spelling mistakes - propagation! Thanks for the help.