# jQuery UI slider to stop event propagation

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I am using [jQuery UI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JQuery_UI) *Slider* in a div which is dragable. On clicking the slider, the event propogated and the div starts to drag! Is there a way to stop its propogation on the mouse down event?

Using return false doesn't work to me.

```
$('#slider-' + boxId).slider(
    {
        step: 0.2,
        min: 0.2,
        max: 2,
        value: [1],
        stop: function( event, ui )
        {
            var value = 0.2;
            value = ui.value;
            $('#' + boxId + ' .timeText').text(value + ' secs');
            $('#' + boxId).attr('data-time' , value);
            _timeLineUtility.reCalculateAll();
            return false;
        },
        slide: function (event, ui)
        {
            return false;
        },
        start: function(event, ui) { return false; }
    });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
event.stopPropagation()
```

http://api.jquery.com/event.stopPropagation/

Here is a possible duplicate - [Stopping propagation of mousedown/mouseup from a click handler](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8875070/stopping-propagation-of-mousedown-mouseup-from-a-click-handler)

Comment: If return false isn't working what's that going to do?  return false should be the same thing as calling both

Comment: Ohhh I got it.. return false dose nothing for the delegate but event.stopPropagation() sets the property to stop it.

Answer (score 1):

Try using this

```
event.stopPropagation()
```