# jQuery slider and draggable div issue - Div slides along with slider

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I'm using the jQuery UI slider inside a draggable div #fullMenu. When dragging the slider, #fullMenu moves too as it's mousedown event is triggered. I read about [stopPropogation](http://api.jquery.com/event.stopPropagation/) and also found this other exact [same question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11063674/jquery-ui-slider-to-stop-event-propagation) but I cant figure out where to call stopPropogation  in my code. Please give me your lights!

```
   $(function() {
        $("#slider-range" ).slider({
            range: true,
            min: 0,
            max: 500,
            values: [ 75, 300 ],
            slide: function( event, ui ) {
                $( "#pricefrom" ).val(ui.values[0]);
                $( "#priceto" ).val(ui.values[1]);
                $( "#pricefromlabel" ).html(ui.values[0]);
                $( "#pricetolabel" ).html(ui.values[1]);
            }
        });
        return false;
    });
```

Here is a [working version](http://ht-webcreations.com/vildiridis/itemlist.php?gid=10) of the page and this is the javascript code for handling the drag events:

```
var Drag = {

    obj : null,

    init : function(o, oRoot, minX, maxX, minY, maxY, bSwapHorzRef, bSwapVertRef, fXMapper, fYMapper)
    {
        o.onmousedown   = Drag.start;

        o.hmode         = bSwapHorzRef ? false : true ;
        o.vmode         = bSwapVertRef ? false : true ;

        o.root = oRoot && oRoot != null ? oRoot : o ;

        if (o.hmode  && isNaN(parseInt(o.root.style.left  ))) o.root.style.left   = "0px";
        if (o.vmode  && isNaN(parseInt(o.root.style.top   ))) o.root.style.top    = "0px";
        if (!o.hmode && isNaN(parseInt(o.root.style.right ))) o.root.style.right  = "0px";
        if (!o.vmode && isNaN(parseInt(o.root.style.bottom))) o.root.style.bottom = "0px";

        o.minX  = typeof minX != 'undefined' ? minX : null;
        o.minY  = typeof minY != 'undefined' ? minY : null;
        o.maxX  = typeof maxX != 'undefined' ? maxX : null;
        o.maxY  = typeof maxY != 'undefined' ? maxY : null;

        o.xMapper = fXMapper ? fXMapper : null;
        o.yMapper = fYMapper ? fYMapper : null;

        o.root.onDragStart  = new Function();
        o.root.onDragEnd    = new Function();
        o.root.onDrag       = new Function();
    },

    start : function(e)
    {
        var o = Drag.obj = this;
        e = Drag.fixE(e);
        var y = parseInt(o.vmode ? o.root.style.top  : o.root.style.bottom);
        var x = parseInt(o.hmode ? o.root.style.left : o.root.style.right );
        o.root.onDragStart(x, y);

        o.lastMouseX    = e.clientX;
        o.lastMouseY    = e.clientY;

        if (o.hmode) {
            if (o.minX != null) o.minMouseX = e.clientX - x + o.minX;
            if (o.maxX != null) o.maxMouseX = o.minMouseX + o.maxX - o.minX;
        } else {
            if (o.minX != null) o.maxMouseX = -o.minX + e.clientX + x;
            if (o.maxX != null) o.minMouseX = -o.maxX + e.clientX + x;
        }

        if (o.vmode) {
            if (o.minY != null) o.minMouseY = e.clientY - y + o.minY;
            if (o.maxY != null) o.maxMouseY = o.minMouseY + o.maxY - o.minY;
        } else {
            if (o.minY != null) o.maxMouseY = -o.minY + e.clientY + y;
            if (o.maxY != null) o.minMouseY = -o.maxY + e.clientY + y;
        }

        document.onmousemove    = Drag.drag;
        document.onmouseup      = Drag.end;

        //Add custom check in IE, if it press scrool drag and drop event is disabled ( scrollbar has id empty )
        document.onmousedown = function(e){ 
        if (typeof e == 'undefined') e = window.event;
        var targ = e.srcElement ? e.srcElement : e.target;
            //window.status="Id:="+targ.parentNode.id;
            if(targ.parentNode.id=="") Drag.end(e) ;
        }

        return false;
    },

    drag : function(e)
    {
        e = Drag.fixE(e);
        var o = Drag.obj;

        var ey  = e.clientY;
        var ex  = e.clientX;
        var y = parseInt(o.vmode ? o.root.style.top  : o.root.style.bottom);
        var x = parseInt(o.hmode ? o.root.style.left : o.root.style.right );
        var nx, ny;

        if (o.minX != null) ex = o.hmode ? Math.max(ex, o.minMouseX) : Math.min(ex, o.maxMouseX);
        if (o.maxX != null) ex = o.hmode ? Math.min(ex, o.maxMouseX) : Math.max(ex, o.minMouseX);
        if (o.minY != null) ey = o.vmode ? Math.max(ey, o.minMouseY) : Math.min(ey, o.maxMouseY);
        if (o.maxY != null) ey = o.vmode ? Math.min(ey, o.maxMouseY) : Math.max(ey, o.minMouseY);

        nx = x + ((ex - o.lastMouseX) * (o.hmode ? 1 : -1));
        ny = y + ((ey - o.lastMouseY) * (o.vmode ? 1 : -1));

        if (o.xMapper)      nx = o.xMapper(y)
        else if (o.yMapper) ny = o.yMapper(x)

        Drag.obj.root.style[o.hmode ? "left" : "right"] = nx + "px";
        Drag.obj.root.style[o.vmode ? "top" : "bottom"] = ny + "px";
        Drag.obj.lastMouseX = ex;
        Drag.obj.lastMouseY = ey;

        Drag.obj.root.onDrag(nx, ny);
        return false;
    },

    end : function()
    {
        document.onmousemove = null;
        document.onmouseup   = null;
        if(Drag.obj){
        Drag.obj.root.onDragEnd(    parseInt(Drag.obj.root.style[Drag.obj.hmode ? "left" : "right"]), 
                                    parseInt(Drag.obj.root.style[Drag.obj.vmode ? "top" : "bottom"]));
        }
        Drag.obj = null;
    },

    fixE : function(e)
    {
        if (typeof e == 'undefined') e = window.event;
        if (typeof e.layerX == 'undefined') e.layerX = e.offsetX;
        if (typeof e.layerY == 'undefined') e.layerY = e.offsetY;
        return e;
    }
};


    //<![CDATA[
    var theHandle = document.getElementById("handle");
    var theRoot   = document.getElementById("fullMenu");
    Drag.init(theHandle, theRoot);
    //]]>
```

Slider functions (from jQuery UI):

```
_start: function (a, b) {
    var c = {
        handle: this.handles[b],
        value: this.value()
    };
    return this.options.values && this.options.values.length && (c.value = this.values(b), c.values = this.values()), this._trigger("start", a, c)
},
_slide: function (a, b, c) {
    var d, e, f;
    this.options.values && this.options.values.length ? (d = this.values(b ? 0 : 1), this.options.values.length === 2 && this.options.range === !0 && (b === 0 && c > d || b === 1 && c < d) && (c = d), c !== this.values(b) && (e = this.values(), e[b] = c, f = this._trigger("slide", a, {
        handle: this.handles[b],
        value: c,
        values: e
    }), d = this.values(b ? 0 : 1), f !== !1 && this.values(b, c, !0))) : c !== this.value() && (f = this._trigger("slide", a, {
        handle: this.handles[b],
        value: c
    }), f !== !1 && this.value(c))
},
_stop: function (a, b) {
    var c = {
        handle: this.handles[b],
        value: this.value()
    };
    this.options.values && this.options.values.length && (c.value = this.values(b), c.values = this.values()), this._trigger("stop", a, c)
},
```

Comment: where is your fiddle? and what have you tried? this question seems like build from **ready codes.**

Comment: There's too much involved in my page to work in a fiddle. I just need to know where the stopPropogation call needs to be placed. Trust me, I've spent hours trying to put all the bit and pieces together, i'm still learning though and not all of it is clear to me.

Comment: Of course the drag.js I've posted is ready, unless someone should write the entire code from scratch each time they are building a new page. I dont get your point.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the solution to the problem I posted in case someone needs it in the future:

```
    $("#slider-range" ).slider({
        range: true,
        min: <?=$startfrom?>,
        max: <?=$endat?>,
        values: [ <?=$minprice?>, <?=$maxprice?> ],

        // where .stopPropogation() needs to be:

        start: function (event, ui) {
            event.stopPropagation();
        },

        slide: function( event, ui ) {
            $( "#pricefrom" ).val(ui.values[0]);
            $( "#priceto" ).val(ui.values[1]);
            $( "#pricefromlabel" ).html(ui.values[0] + ' &euro;');
            $( "#pricetolabel" ).html(ui.values[1] + ' &euro;');
        }
    });
```

Comment: Cleaned it up in my code so it's obvious it is in the `.slider({})`

Answer (score 1):

You have `return false;` (which does both `event.preventDefault()` & `event.stopPropogation()`) at the end of your *start* event, but the problem is, you need this / or `stopPropogation()` within the events of your **slider**.

Since your slider is returning a value, we can't use *return false* here.

You also have the parameters strangely named for the UI events. jQuery UI events have two parameters: **`(event, ui)`**

```
$('#whatever').slider({

    start: function(event, ui) { 
        // your code

        event.stopPropogation(); // put it here
    }

});
```

But you seem to be passing in different variables (a, b). Is there any way you can get the original `event` so you can stopPropogation?

Comment: The _start function by default return the values of the slider, where do I put return false; Pls check my updated post to see what I mean.

Comment: I finally found the solution with more searching and your suggestions.

Comment: Great! Update your Question and add some info on what the answer ended up being up there too